# How to stop transfer of large raster into arcsde geodatabase

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-desktop, raster, enterprise-geodatabase

I have just realised that I will not have enough space on my harddrive to accomodate a raster which is being copied into an arcsde geodatadatabase. I am afraid, that if I stop the process in ArcCatalog, I will corrupt the raster in the geodatabase and not be able to delete it...or even worse corrupt the whole database.

Can anyone advise me on how to stop the copying process and ensure that the sde Geodatabase will not hold any remnants.

Arcsde9.3 / ArcCatalog 10.0 / MSSQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can kill the loading process on the client OS or kill the database session from the database.

The active raster being updated would likely be damaged, but you are unlikely to damage the geodatabase as a whole (certainly less so than letting the database overfill).  Repair steps would be dependent on what kind of loading was being done.

It is no longer best practice to place rasters in ArcSDE, and well on the way to something which is not recommended.  If you used mosaic datasets and the other raster advances in ArcGIS that resulted from integration of the former Image Server you wouldn't be running out of database storage.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. How should rasters be managed then? How else can I serve raster data in a arcgis server environment other than through an arcsde database?

Comment: Starting at 9.2, and running through 10.2, ArcGIS Server has received significant new capabilities in raster management with each release.  The options with modern software are too broad to fit one of these tiny comment boxes.  http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/009t/009t00000208000000.htm

Comment: Ok Thanks..I had to cancel the copy operation in ArcCatalog which seems to now be frozen. Any idea how I can now remove the corrupt data which I now have in MSSQL? Should I stop the ArcCatalog process...or will something be happening in the background?  Any advice regarding repair steps to the mssql database?

Comment: http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/100552-How-to-deal-with-corrupted-raster-data-in-arcsde

Comment: Oh well....Now I can´t connect to my sde Geodatabase...so I guess the whole GDB is now corrupt. Thats about  4 weeks of work out the window then!

Comment: I've had hundreds of raster loads crash due to environmental factors, and the only geodatabases that were corrupted were when the physical filesystems failed.  Take a step back, restart the database, then start working the issue with Tech Support.